# How to diagonalize this circulant matrix?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, circulant-matrices

I came across a matrix diagonalization problem in reading a physics paper, can someone tell me how to diagonalize this kind of matrix?
    \begin{equation}
   \begin{bmatrix}
  a_{1} &  c_{1}  & \ldots & c_{n-1}\\
  c_{n-1}  &  a_{2} & \ldots & c_{n-2}\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
  c_{1}  &   c_{2}       &\ldots & a_{n}
  \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation}
in which $c_j = \exp{i2j\pi/n}$.
Thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix

Comment: I have seen that, but this one is different, the diagonal element varies with the index

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula for computing its inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check it but I think the idea is there :

---

Let $c(n)  =e^{-2i \pi (n-1) / N}\ \ $ a $N \times 1$ column vector. Your matrix is $M = c c^H+A$ with $A$ diagonal $A_{n,n} = a_n-1$.

The eigenvalue  equation $M x=  b x$ becomes $ \langle x,c\rangle c= (bI-A)x$ i.e. $x(n) = \frac{\langle x,c\rangle}{b+1-a(n)}c(n)$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{b+1-a(n)} = 1$.

Assuming there are $N$ solutions $b(1),\ldots, b(N)$ for $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{b+1-a(n)} = 1$ you get
$M = P \Lambda P^{-1}$ with $\Lambda_{n,n} = b(n)$ and $P_{n,m} = \frac{c(n)}{b(m)+1-a(n)}$

Comment: Thanks very much! This is the exactly the result of the paper.